# Убрать бессмысленную часть XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

Как убрать бессмысленное содержимое `xsl:text` в в начале документа `xml` с включенными стилями `xslt`? (подробности в скриншоте)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#styles"?>
<!DOCTYPE notebook SYSTEM "ntb.dtd">
<записная_книжка>
    <xsl:stylesheet  id='styles' version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
        <xsl:template match="фио">
            <xsl:text>ФИО:&#xA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@фамилия" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@имя" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@отчество" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="адрес">
            <xsl:text>Адрес:&#xA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@индекс" />
            <xsl:text>, г. </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@город" />
            <xsl:text>, ул. </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@улица" />
            <xsl:text>, дом. </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@дом" />
            <xsl:text>, кв. </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@квартира" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
    <запись>
        <фио фамилия="Иванов" имя="Петр" отчество="Михайлович" />
        <день_рождения>25.03.1977</день_рождения>
        <адрес индекс="660059" город="Красноярск" улица="Вавилова" дом="102" квартира="35" />
        <телефон мобильный="89234573764" домашний="8 391 285 54 47" рабочий="8 391 240 04 78" />
    </запись>
    <запись>
        <фио фамилия="Петров" имя="Иван" отчество="Алексеевич" />
        <день_рождения>5.08.1990</день_рождения>
        <адрес индекс="663091" город="Дивногорск" улица="Гагарина" дом="74" квартира="108" />
        <телефон мобильный="89233654458" домашний="8 39144 3 70 07" рабочий="8 391 244 15 95" />
    </запись>
</записная_книжка>
```

[image: результат просмотра документа в Mozilla Firefox]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не самый удачный вариант использования. Предлагаю использовать отдельный файл для стиля.

Если хочется продолжать, то [радуемся](https://www.google.ru/search?q=Embed%20xsl%20into%20an%20XML%20file&oq=Embed%20xsl%20into%20an%20XML%20file&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Ответ - можно. Посмотрите пожалуйста на пример из [этой статьи](http://www.java2s.com/Code/XML/XSLT-stylesheet/Embeddedstylesheetintoxmldocument.htm).

В примере нет ни одного <xsl:text>? но вы можете добавить его самостоятельно и убедится, что никаких "лишних" вставок это не повлечет.

Кроме этого, посмотрите на свой скриншот еще раз, но внимательно. Вы можете увидеть, что не отображается не только содержимое <xsl:text>, но и пустые строки для других элементов шаблона.

Comment: Да, я знаю о том что если XSL в отдельном документе, то его видно не будет, но если они объединены в один XML, то все элементы `<xsl:text>` отображаются на экране. Вопрос в том можно ли заставить браузер игнорировать отображение `<xsl:text>` в описании XSL

Comment: Ответ - можно. см. уточнение ответа.